# Google Sheets: Find Last and Second-Last Non Blank Values in a Table Column Based on Date; There are Tables Above and Below It

Tags: date, google-sheets, filter, conditional-statements, nonblank

I have a Google Sheet with many different, separate tables starting in different rows.  I want to find the **last and second-last nonblank value** in a particular column **inside one specific table**.

The nuance here is my table starts in row 89 and ends in row 141.  **I have other tables both above and below it sharing the same columns E and F.**

For the purposes of my sample table I'm just going to include a smaller number of rows.

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1/7/2024 | 3 |
| 1/14/2024 | 10 |
| 1/21/2024 | 11 |
| 1/28/2024 | 14 |
| 2/4/2024 | 3 |
| 2/11/2024 |  |
| 2/18/2024 |  |
| 2/25/2024 |  |
| 3/3/2024 |  |
| 3/10/2024 |  |
| 3/17/2024 |  |
| 3/24/2024 |  |
| 3/31/2024 |  |
| 4/7/2024 |  |
| 4/14/2024 |  |
| 4/21/2024 |  |
| 4/28/2024 |  |
| 5/5/2024 |  |
| 5/12/2024 |  |
| 5/19/2024 |  |
| 5/26/2024 |  |

In a different cell in my Google Sheet, I want it to populate with 3 (associated with date 2/4/2024).  In another cell I want it to populate with 14 (associated with date 1/28/2024).  These numbers correspond to the last and second last non-blank values in the "Value" column, respectively.  The "Value" column is located in column F while the "Date" column is located in column E of my Google Sheet.

Below are the formulas I tried:

- Last (Non-Blank) Value: `=filter(F90:F110,E90:E110=large(E90:E110,1))`
- Second-Last (Non-Blank) Value: `=filter(F90:F111,E90:E111=large(E90:E111,2))`

But both formulas return blanks because they consider dates associated with blank values in "Value" column.

How can I fix my formulas to get my desired outputs?

Answer (score 2):

*You may try this for last `non-blank` (***date_column*** is not taken into account):*

```js
=chooserows(tocol(F89:F141,1),-1)
```

- *Change `-1` to `-2` for ***second-last****